# Server on virtual machine setup?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, node.js

I just started to learn about networking and decided to run my own node.js server 
The problem is i have almost no idea what im doing :(
I installed a virtual ubuntu 64 server, installed nodejs and all the prereqs.
I downloaded a sample (https://github.com/ry/node_chat) and dont know if its working or not. 
i run node on the server file and get "server running at 127.0.0.1:1337"
How do i see it on my host (physical) machine?

Thanks!!

ps i have no domain, virtual is running on NAT network and my physical is behind a router

Comment: check the VM IP, and use that and check FW rules

Comment: when i run ifconfig on the server i get: "eth0 10.0.2.15, lo 127.0.0.1"
ipconfig on physical gives gateway:192.168.2.1 ip4:192.168.2.28
what should i do now?
btw thx so much for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your virtual machine (ubuntu 64bit) start the terminal and run

```
ifconfig
```

This should give you the ip address assigned to your virtual machine (192.168.x.x) something like that. On your host open up a browser and type in http://192.168.x.x: in your case  will be 1337.

I would recommend you configure your VM to always have that ip static and setup the hosts files on your host machine to point to the ip address, making it easier to get to the server.

Comment: when i run ifconfig on the server i get: "eth0 10.0.2.15, lo 127.0.0.1" ipconfig on physical gives gateway:192.168.2.1 ip4:192.168.2.28 what should i do now? btw thx so much for the reply

Comment: have you tried going to http://192.168.2.28:1337 from your host?

Comment: thanks guys, finally got it to work. 
for future references, i put my virtual machine network on "host only"  so there is a "virtual" driver with ip 192.168.52.1 and i could connect thusly!